# VB script Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to extract data from a file named `ABC.txt`. Insted, I want to open a pop-up window to select the file.

Can someone provide me code to do this?

```
Const Extract_Temp As String = "D:\Work\Tool_Specific\ABC.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `FileDialog` object:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog, aFile As Variant

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
fd.title = "Pick a file."
fd.Show

aFile = fd.SelectedItems(1)

Set fd = Nothing
```

EDIT

You must reference the "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" (or "14.0", or whichever version you have) to use this code. VBA editor, go to Tools/References...